# Maven -Dtest=* test, does not seem to run all tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, continuous-integration, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a Jenkins CI server that is set up with a Selenium test project running with maven-surefire. I need the project to be a parameterized build, so that I can trigger the build via URL with a Dtest as a parameter  (and only run the tests I specify in the url). This works great.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to figure out how to run ALL of the tests, while in this parameterized configuration. Since it is in parameterized build mode, I must ALWAYS specify the -Dtest parameter.

Based on the [Surefire documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html), it seems like I should be able to wildcard the test names, and everything will be run:

```
-Dtest=* or -Dtest=Test*
```

The odd result of running these parameters is a print statement (that I created) from all `6` of the tests (denoting that they were all started):

```
"Test <test_name> started, click here to see the SauceLabs video"
```

And then the standard test result (below) for only 4/6 tests

```
Running <test_class_path>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.048 sec
```

Followed by the summary:

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

If it matters, the tests are being run in parallel using surefire, and one other odd thing is that while printing out the individual test results, after the 4th one, the 5th result starts printing, but never shows a result, and includes a $1 at the end:

```
Running <test_class_path>$1
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything or answer any questions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Don't use back ticks ` use simple quotes like this ' for the quoting. First try.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain Maven debug (normally `-X`) flag in your configuration? Perhaps you can [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the output?

Comment: In that surefire documentation is `mvn -Dtest=TestCi*le test` intentionally meant to look like a test named Testicle?

Comment: If you run maven without Jenkins, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @user944849 - yeah, I do

Comment: @Duncan Jones - given that it is with Jenkins I was unable to use the -X option

Comment: If you don't run the tests in parallel, is the behavior the same?

Comment: does anything change if you explicitly specify all six testcases for Dtest?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's a regular expession:

`mvn -Dtest=.*`

works for me.